# Cannot resolve constructor 'ArrayList(java.util.List<T>)` in Java

Tags: java

I am trying to create an array list of Libraries my application uses to create an instance of. I have an abstract class which they extend so I can use the same `Class<T>`

```
abstract class Library {}
abstract class SomeLib extends Library {}
```

I now want to create this array list, this is how I am trying to do it:

```
public ArrayList<Class<Library>> libs = new ArrayList<Class<Library>>(
        Arrays.asList(SomeLib.class)
);
```

However, I get this error:

> Cannot resolve constructor 'ArrayList(java.util.List)`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It should be `ArrayList<Class<? extends Library>>`.

Comment: Thank-you so much @JohannesKuhn

Comment: Why at all is there some "Class"? What about ```public ArrayList<Library> libs = new ArrayList<Library>();```

Comment: Because that would require them to be instanced already, I want the ability for developers to add there libraries in which get instanced when the rest of them do later on in the script. Its a wrapper for something @Islingre

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I already said in the comments, use `ArrayList<Class<? extends Library>>`.

The reason for this is simple: `SomeLib.class` has the type `Class<SomeLib>`, which is not a `Class<Library>`.

But if you make the generic a bit looser, by allowing it's subclasses (as you want to do), then `Class<SomeLib>` matches `Class<? extends Library>`, and everything works fine.